# Android : Any open source Android twitter client application?

Tags: android, open-source, twitter, twitter-client

I want any easy open source android twitter client application.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Twimight 
https://code.google.com/p/twimight/

It's a fully functional open source Twitter client originating from an academic research project.

Answer (score 3):

- [andtweet](http://code.google.com/p/andtweet/)
- [nanotweeter](http://code.google.com/p/nanotweeter/)
- [atweeter](http://code.google.com/p/atweeter/)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out twidere on github https://github.com/mariotaku/twidere. It is open source and the author is in need of people to participate.

Answer (score 1):

try these

http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php

http://code.google.com/p/andtweet/

http://code.google.com/p/nanotweeter/

http://code.google.com/p/android-twitter-googlemaps/

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **the** Twitter app is open source.
Please see http://appmodo.com/18732/twitter-launches-open-source-app-for-android/

Comment: Sorry -- the source code was never released for this app.

Comment: Yeah they said that but they haven't release the source yet.